# Using SHELL BSD "date" command for conversion to Nanoseconds?

Tags: macos, shell, unix

I need to convert a time to nanoseconds, the bsd date command isn't suitable, as the best it can returns are seconds.. `date +"%H:%M:%S"` returns `17:33:07`..

Seems there is a difference between Mac's BSD date version, and the Linux GNU one. The last one can return nanoseconds. The first can't..

Should I be using python or ruby scripts instead of shell? Or is there another solution to get my nanoseconds on a Mac?

no in fact no `%N`

Comment: `date --v` to see what version you're using

Comment: Thats the problem mac is using a bsd version of date which doesn't support `+"%N"`. Also if you search the man page on your mac you won't find `%N` anywhere in there

Comment: so a solution for this?

Comment: @ozama you might want to update your post with this information.

Answer (score 2):

The OSX `date` command doesn't do nanonseconds, but in OSX you can still get this from the system.

For example, in C, this should be the system uptime:

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <mach/mach_time.h>

int main(void)
{
        uint64_t t = mach_absolute_time();

        // Get ratio between mach_absolute_time units and nanoseconds.
        mach_timebase_info_data_t data;
        mach_timebase_info(&data);

        // Convert to nanoseconds.
        t *= data.numer;
        t /= data.denom;

        printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", t);

        return 0;
}
```

Save this to something like `uptimens.c`, then run `make uptimens` from your shell.

```
mac:~ ghoti$ ./uptimens
366181198555774
mac:~ ghoti$
```

Comment: Great! can you add an input argument that looks like H:M:S.N which will be converted to a Linux time? I'm not a c guy :\

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "Linux time"?  And exactly what are you looking for -- the current time, or do you want to be able to adjust it using text interpretation like Linux's `date -d ...`?  If the latter, you're probably out of luck.  In fact, it might be valuable for you to tell us what you're trying to achieve here.  This might just be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: Yes it may be; actually i want to cut an mp3 file from both sides lets say in t1 and t2.. seems that i can use `ffmpeg -ss t1 -t t2` to do. But I need a script to apply to lot of files with a non constant length, so i use some "sed" to get the file length then I do a minus something in microsecondes... and here i'm I, I can't get enough precision in milliseconds.. do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 2):

I differentiate code for the mac using a test for the presence of the `--version` option:

```
if ! date --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then # Mac
    micro=$(perl -e 'use Time::HiRes qw( gettimeofday ); my ($a, $b) = gettimeofday; print $b;')
else
    micro=$(($(date +%N) / 1000))
fi
```

The best accuracy for `gettimeofday` is microseconds, though.

Answer (score -2):

```
$ date +%T.%N
11:05:07.894987100
```

This gives you the current time with nanosecond accuracy.

Comment: Not on Mac:
```$ date +%T.%N -> 13:18:20.N```